# Hasse diagram for incomparable elements

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

If $L=\{a,b,c\},$ which are incomparable to each other, what will be the Hasse diagram in that case? Will the three points lie on the plane arbitrarily?

Also is there any necessity that elements must be put in the same orientation (I'm talking about left or right orientation) if I draw it separately? For example:
[image: look at it]

Can I shift the positions of $10$ and $15,$ or can I bring $20$ slightly down between $4$ and $15$ (obviously above $4$)?

Comment: The 4 is not comparable with either 10 or 15, so it doesn't matter whether it's above or below them. The only relations in a Hasse diagram are those implied by following a single branch upward through nodes.

Comment: thanks @coffeemath

Comment: The answer is yes to your first question. If all elements are incomparable, that is called an anti-chain, and it doesn't matter if two nodes are above one another or side by side since there is no connection between them, and so the relative position on the plane has no meaning. In a Hasse diagram, left or right has no meaning: if two elements are related, one must be above the other (higher in the $y$ axis); otherwise, see the answer to the first question. The third question was answered by coffeemath.